# MS Access get ISO standard week number

Tags: ms-access, iso, week-number

I'm surprised that I can't find any existing solutions to this online but I just need an SQL function that returns an ISO standard week number (i.e. the start of week 1 is always the first Monday of the year).

None of the DatePart function options consistently return the correct result. I had thought the option "vbFirstFourDays - Start with the first week that has at least four days in the new year." but testing it for today (12th Jan) returns week 3, not week 2 (my expression is `DatePart("ww",Now(),2)` )

This year ISO week 1 starts on 4th Jan, next Year the 2nd Jan and last year it was the 5th of Jan.

Many thanks

Comment: Try `DatePart("ww",Now(),2,2)`. Your example was actually omitting the *firstweekofyear* argument.

Comment: Oops, silly of me, thanks a lot, works fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DatePart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa) function does indeed calculate the ISO-8601 week number almost<sup>*</sup> correctly when it uses `vbMonday` for the *firstdayofweek* argument and `vbFirstFourDays` for the *firstweekofyear* argument, e.g.,

```vbs
DatePart("ww", Date(), vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
```

or, when used directly in an Access query

```vbs
DatePart("ww", Date(), 2, 2)
```

<sup>*</sup> Note that the bug documented [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/200299) has apparently never been fixed, so the following Mondays in the 21<sup>st</sup> century are reported as being in week 53 when according to ISO-8601 they should be in week 1 of the following year:

2003-12-29
2007-12-31
2019-12-30
2031-12-29
2035-12-31
2047-12-30
2059-12-29
2063-12-31
2075-12-30
2087-12-29
2091-12-31

Comment: Does Access propagate [the Oleaut23.dll bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200299)?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes it does. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just to follow on from Gord Thompson, Microsoft have provided a workaround which returns the correct ISO week in all circumstances. It simply changes week 53 to week 1. Simply place this in a VBA Module and then you'll be able to use the function in Excel/Access.

```
Public Function ISOWeek(MyDate As Date) As Integer

      ISOWeek = Format(MyDate, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
      If ISOWeek > 52 Then
         If Format(MyDate + 7, "ww", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 2 Then ISOWeek = 1
      End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more problems with the ISO weeknumbers than just the 2 week digits returned by DatePart.

January 1st on a Friday should be in week 53 of the previous year

December 31 on a Monday should be in week 1 of the next year

A lot of businesses in Europe use a four digit number to show year and week together. In those cases:

Friday #01/01/2021# should be shown as week "2153"

Monday #12/31/2018# should be shown as week "1901"

I have created 2 wrappers around the DatePart function to add the correct year and show the right weeknumber in case DatePart is in error.

```
Public Function ISO_YYWW(dat As Date) As String ' ISO 8601 / NEN 2772
    Dim ww As Integer
    ww = CInt(ISO_WW(dat))
    If ww >= 52 And Val(Format(dat, "ww")) <= 2 Then
       ISO_YYWW = Format(((Year(dat) - 1) Mod 100), "00") & Format(ww, "00")
    ElseIf ww = 1 And Month(dat) = 12 Then
       ISO_YYWW = Format(((Year(dat) + 1) Mod 100), "00") & Format(ww, "00")
    Else
       ISO_YYWW = Format(dat, "YY") & Format(ww, "00")
    End If
End Function
Public Function ISO_WW(dat As Date) As String ' ISO 8601 / NEN 2772
    If Format(dat, "DD-MM") = "31-12" And DatePart("W", dat, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 1 Then ' 31-dec on a monday
       ISO_WW = "01"
    ElseIf Format(dat, "DD-MM") = "30-12" And DatePart("W", dat, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 1 Then ' 30-dec on a monday
       ISO_WW = "01"
    ElseIf Format(dat, "DD-MM") = "29-12" And DatePart("W", dat, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = 1 Then ' 29-dec on a monday
       ISO_WW = "01"
    Else
       ISO_WW = Format(DatePart("ww", dat, 2, 2), "00")
    End If
End Function
```

I have tested from 1970 to 2021 and found no problems using this code

```
Sub test()
    Dim dat As Date, yy As Integer, f As Integer
    f = FreeFile
    Open CodeDb.Name & ".txt" For Output As #f
    Print #f, "date", "day", "ISO_WW / DOW", "ISO_YYWW"
    For yy = 1970 To 2021
        For dat = CDate("31/12/" & yy) - 7 To CDate("31/12/" & yy) + 7
            If ISO_WW(dat) >= 52 Or ISO_WW(dat) = "53" Or Val(ISO_WW(dat)) = 1 Then
               Print #f, Format(dat, "yyyy-mm-dd"), Format(dat, "DDD"), ISO_WW(dat) & " / " & DatePart("W", dat, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays), ISO_YYWW(dat)
            End If
        Next dat
        Print #f, ""
    Next yy
    Close #f
End Sub
```