# Microsoft Access Form using "Date Code" to be autogenerated but is always 1 week behind

Tags: ms-access, office365

I'm not fluent in Access and am trying to figure out why the date code field is not propagating correctly.  The field [Screenshot of Date Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLG5N.png) shows up as YYWWDD (Last two digits of Year, Week number of year, and day of work week (Monday = 1 - Friday = 5), but for the last two years the Week number of year has consistently been 1 week behind.  As seen in the screenshot Date Code 20242  this is actually the 25 week since the first week of January.

the code in the property sheet is as follows:

```
=IIf(IsNull([DaySelected]),IIf(Len(Format(Date(),"ww",2,3))=1,Format(Date(),"yy") & "0" & Format(Date(),"ww w",2,3),Format(Date(),"yywww ",2,3)),IIf(Len(Format(Date(),"ww",2,3))=1,Format(Date(),"yy") & "0" & Format(Date(),"ww",2,3) & [DaySelected],Format(Date(),"yyww",2,3) & [DaySelected]))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34742007/2144390

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, that the year is the ISO 8601 year, not the calendar year, and a custom function is needed to obtain the true ISO 8601 week number:

```vb
' Returns the ISO 8601 week of a date.
' The related ISO year is returned by ref.
'
' 2016-01-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Week( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Optional ByRef IsoYear As Integer) _
    As Integer

    Const MaxWeekValue           As Integer = 53
    Const MinWeekValue           As Integer = 1
    Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12
    Const MinMonthValue          As Integer = 1

    Dim Month       As Integer
    Dim Interval    As String
    Dim Result      As Integer

    Interval = "ww"

    Month = VBA.Month(Date1)
    ' Initially, set the ISO year to the calendar year.
    IsoYear = VBA.Year(Date1)

    Result = DatePart(Interval, Date1, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
    If Result = MaxWeekValue Then
        If DatePart(Interval, DateAdd(Interval, 1, Date1), vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = MinWeekValue Then
            ' OK. The next week is the first week of the following year.
        Else
            ' This is really the first week of the next ISO year.
            ' Correct for DatePart bug.
            Result = MinWeekValue
        End If
    End If

    ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
    If Month = MinMonthValue Then
        If Result >= MaxWeekValue - 1 Then
            ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear - 1
        End If
    ElseIf Month = MaxMonthValue Then
        If Result = MinWeekValue Then
            ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear + 1
        End If
    End If

    ' IsoYear is returned by reference.
    Week = Result

End Function
```

Then, build a simple custom function to generate your year-week-day number:

```vb
Public Function FormatWeekDayIso8601(ByVal DaySelected As Integer) As String

    Dim Result              As String

    Dim IsoYear As Integer
    Dim IsoWeek As Integer

    IsoWeek = Week(Date, IsoYear)
    Result = _
        CStr(IsoYear Mod 100) & _
        VBA.Format(IsoWeek, String(2, "0")) & _
        CStr(DaySelected)

    FormatWeekDayIso8601 = Result

End Function
```

Now, use it like this:

```
=FormatWeekDayIso8601(Nz([DaySelected],1))
```

Comment: No. They will replace it completely - as shown in the last line.

Comment: Works Great!! Thanks for the help.